# How do i make a jQuery menu click?

Tags: jquery, html

To make a long question short: For example, on godaddy.com they have a menu. Say you're trying to click "hosting" on their menu. It's right next to webtools and websites, but on my site if you click the word hosting nothing happens. It will not take you to the hosting page of the website. That's my problem, how do I get my menu to click? The code I'm using is below.

I am using this template, the default `home.html` file came like this:

```
<!-- Begin Navigation -->
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Order">Order</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Log in">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

My js function looks like this: when I add `click()` anywhere in the function the menu clicks, but the jQuery slider stops working. How do I make the menu clickable without affecting any of the other jQuery ran stuff in my website?

```
$(function () {
    $("#navigation ul").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout",
        speed: 700,
        click: function (event, menuItem) {
            $('#navigation li.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#slider ul.slider-items').jcarousel({
        'scroll': 1,
            'auto': 7,
            'wrap': 'both',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: {
            onAfterAnimation: function (c, o, i, s) {
                jQuery('.slider-nav li').removeClass('active');
                jQuery('.slider-nav li:eq(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });

    $('.widget .button').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('button-act');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('button-act');
    });

    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6) {
        DD_belatedPNG.fix('#header, h1#logo a, li.back, li.back .left, #slider, .frame, ul.slider-items li h2, .slider-nav, .nav-inner, #main-top, #main-bot, #main-cnt, .side-outer, .side-bottom, .side-inner, .widget h2, #slider .button, #slider .button span, .comment, .post-info, .separator');
    }
});

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    $('.slider-nav .nav-inner').append('<ul></ul>');
    var i = 1;
    $('.slider-items li').each(function () {
        $('.slider-nav ul').append('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>');
        i++;
    });
    $('.slider-nav .nav-inner').append('<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>');
    $('.slider-nav li:last').addClass('last');
    $('.slider-nav a').bind('click', function () {
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
        return false;
    });
    $('.slider-nav').css('margin-top', function () {
        return -($(this).find('.nav-inner').outerHeight() / 2 + 7) + 'px';
    });
};
```

Comment: try and comment this line `return false;`

Comment: how do i comment it? is it like this "return false;"

Comment: I repaired your writing style for Christmas.

Comment: LOL thanks i just approved the edit

Comment: like this.. `//return false`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#navigation ul li a").click(function(){ alert('click'); });
```

Does this (inserted in line 11) not work either?

Comment: when i entered that into line 11 a white box comes up at the top of the browser it says the page at "the domain name" says click ... overall no it does not work it still doesn't click and go to the page in the menu